# C++ Get Point on 3D Vector with Shortest Distance to given Point

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, point

I have given a 3D Line which is represented with two 3D Vectors (start-, endpoint), all in **C++**

```
vec3 x1 = [x,y,z]
vec3 x2 = [x,y,z]
```

also i have a 3D Point

```
vec3 x0 = [x,y,z]
```

I want to find the Point **p** which has the shortest distance **d** to my Point **x0** from my given line. 
Here's an image as an example:

[image: Get Point **P** on given Line Segment]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's pure mathematics. It's more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the equation of your line

p = x1 + t (x2 - x1)

The closest point p is such that the vector x0 - p is perpendicular to the line. (You can prove this with Pythagoras / elementary calculus).

Therefore you need

(p - x0) . (x2 - x1) = 0

where . is the dot product.

(x1 - x0 + t (x2 - x1)) . (x2 - x1) = 0

t = - [ (x1 - x0) . (x2 - x1) ] / |x2 - x1|^2

where |x2 - x1| is the magnitude.

Plug this into the first equation to find the p you want.

(PS sorry I couldn't format the equations)

Comment: Thank you very much!:) helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could project the vector x1->x0 onto the vector x1->x2, and then your point p will be x1 + projected vector. Something like this:

```
if (x1 == x2)
    return x1;

vector x1x0 = x0 - x1;
vector x1x2 = x2 - x1;

float t = x1x0.dot(x1x2) / x1x2.SquaredLength();

if (t <= 0.0)
    return x1;
else if(t >= 1.0)
    return x2;
else
    return x1 + t * x1x2;
```